# Compare speech and train a model with limited data

Tags: machine-learning, speech-to-text

I'm trying to do a small project in machine learning, but don't know much.

Let's say I have 50 people saying the sentence "Hi, how are you".

Then I want to train a model that will check when I say:

```
"Hi, how are you" => Good

"Hi, bow are you" => Wrong
```

- Note that I don't care about the meaning of the sentence or if the
  words are correct. I just wanna check that what I'm saying is the
  same as what the other 50 people said.
- Note also that the spoken language that I'm gonna use isn't English.

What's the easiest way to achieve this?
Use speech to text and then just compare (I do have the text as well). but since the sentences are not english, open source speech to text might not be very good.

Use something like Kaldi to train the model?

Any other way?

Answer (score 1):

If it is just one sentence, I guess a small amount of recordings will be sufficient for your project. You can record different voices of saying "hi how are you", and create your data according to this tutorial:

[kaldi-asr data prep tutorial](http://kaldi-asr.org/doc/data_prep.html)

Then, you can use [a Kaldi recipe](https://github.com/kaldi-asr/kaldi/tree/master/egs/commonvoice/s5) doing all the job for you if your data and dictionary is ready. After the training, you could just test your model (decode some new audio) if it has low WER (word error rate). IF your WER is low enough, you could just use this model for your project.